# oracle - summarize table with value group by with distinct value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

i have table like this :

```
school    grade     type      
------    -----     -----
sc1        g1        t1
sc2        g2        t1
sc3        g4        t3
sc4        g3        t2
sc1        g2        t3
```

... etc

- column grade has 4 distinct value g1,g2,g3,g4
- column type has 3 distinct value t1,t2,t3
- column school has 120 distinct value

and i shoud get Summary like this table :(for each distinct column 1-school-)

```
school g1    g2   g3    g4    sum(g1+g2+g3+g4)   t1  t2  t3 sum(t1+t2+t3)
sc1      3    5     1     1             10        21  4   2       27
sc2      2    4     5     5             16        5   23  1       29
```

etc....

How can I write this query to give me the desired result I achieved part of this job by using report builder V6i

- i get all number of distinct school in 1st level and order them ascending
- i make query for each value (g1,g2,g3,g4,t1,t2,t3)
  i want to get that table in sql query without using report

Comment: where are those values for grades and types coming from?

Comment: this value is count of each value in

Comment: Can there be `null`s in the `grade` and/or `type` columns? Otherwise how does the sum of "grades" not equal the sum of "types"?

Comment: no null value in any column.

Comment: no relation between type and grade but total final sum for whole types must be same grades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional aggregation:

```
with
     like_this ( school, grade, typ ) as (
       select 'sc1', 'g1', 't1' from dual union all
       select 'sc2', 'g2', 't1' from dual union all
       select 'sc3', 'g4', 't3' from dual union all
       select 'sc4', 'g3', 't2' from dual union all
       select 'sc1', 'g2', 't3' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select school,
       count(case when grade = 'g1' then 1 end) as g1,
       count(case when grade = 'g2' then 1 end) as g2,
       count(case when grade = 'g3' then 1 end) as g3,
       count(case when grade = 'g4' then 1 end) as g4,
       count(grade)                             as total_g,
       count(case when grade = 't1' then 1 end) as t1,
       count(case when grade = 't2' then 1 end) as t2,
       count(case when grade = 't3' then 1 end) as t3,
       count(typ)                               as total_t
from   like_this
group by school
order by school  --  optional
;

SCH      G1      G2      G3      G4 TOTAL_G      T1      T2      T3 TOTAL_T
--- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
sc1       1       1       0       0       2       0       0       0       2
sc2       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       0       1
sc3       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       1
sc4       0       0       1       0       1       0       0       0       1

4 rows selected.
```